# Phonegap android 4.1 fatal signal 11 while working fine in 2.2

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, xml-parsing

Hello i am developing an app in which i am fetching png images encoded using base64 in XML form.
In android 2.2 emulator and device images are displaying , but when i try it on android 4.1 emulator app crash and showing these log in locat

```
01-22 11:05:03.104: W/dalvikvm(723): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception             pending
01-22 11:05:03.114: W/dalvikvm(723):              in Landroid/webkit/JWebCoreJavaBridge;.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue:()V (FindClass)
01-22 11:05:03.114: W/dalvikvm(723): Pending exception is:
01-22 11:05:03.114: I/dalvikvm(723): java.lang.NullPointerException:
01-22 11:05:03.114: I/dalvikvm(723):    at    android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
01-22 11:05:03.124: I/dalvikvm(723):    at    android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
01-22 11:05:03.124: I/dalvikvm(723):    at    android.webkit.BrowserFrame.inputStreamForAndroidResource(BrowserFrame.java:743)
01-22 11:05:03.124: I/dalvikvm(723):    at    android.webkit.BrowserFrame.shouldInterceptRequest(BrowserFrame.java:831)
01-22 11:05:03.124: I/dalvikvm(723):    at    android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue(Native Method)
01-22 11:05:03.124: I/dalvikvm(723):    at    android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:113)
01-22 11:05:03.124: I/dalvikvm(723):    at    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 11:05:03.124: I/dalvikvm(723):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 11:05:03.184: I/dalvikvm(723):    at    android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:827)
01-22 11:05:03.184: I/dalvikvm(723):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-22 11:05:03.184: I/dalvikvm(723): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
01-22 11:05:03.184: I/dalvikvm(723):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x411f4768     self=0x2a1331d0
01-22 11:05:03.184: I/dalvikvm(723):   | sysTid=736 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps     handle=705675736
01-22 11:05:03.184: I/dalvikvm(723):   | schedstat=( 23820080331 8061777219 3043 )     utm=2200 stm=182 core=0
01-22 11:05:03.276: I/dalvikvm(723):   #00  pc 00001260  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so     (unwind_backtrace_thread+27)
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #01  pc 0005f664  /system/lib/libdvm.so     (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+35)
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #02  pc 00053518  /system/lib/libdvm.so     (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+303)
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #03  pc 000535b2  /system/lib/libdvm.so (    dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #04  pc 00038cfa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #05  pc 000419d4  /system/lib/libdvm.so 
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #06  pc 0037edc8  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #07  pc 002392be  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #08  pc 0023342c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #09  pc 00231e42  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #10  pc 00231e8a  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #11  pc 00231eb6  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #12  pc 00231118  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.284: I/dalvikvm(723):   #13  pc 0017fee6  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #14  pc 0017e6c4  /system/lib/libwebcore.so  
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #15  pc 001418aa  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #16  pc 00140d64  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #17  pc 00140f82  /system/lib/libwebcor e.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #18  pc 00135b0e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #19  pc 00134a04  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #20  pc 00132296  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #21  pc 0013190c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #22  pc 00134780  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #23  pc 0013503a  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #24  pc 001354b4  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #25  pc 0013dbfe  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #26  pc 0011dc68  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #27  pc 002eb6da  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #28  pc 002e0d1e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #29  pc 003b5f4e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #30  pc 003b644a  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   #31  pc 0031f8dc  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   at     android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue(Native Method)
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   at     android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:113)
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   at     android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:827)


01-22 11:05:03.296: I/dalvikvm(723):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-22 11:05:03.304: E/dalvikvm(723): VM aborting
01-22 11:05:03.325: A/libc(723): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1),     thread 736 (WebViewCoreThre)
```

Please help me if anybody know this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to test your application on Real android device. Sometime emulators don't work normally.